# How to migrate/move Amazon's EIP from standard to VPC scope?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to migrate/move ElasticIP from standard scope to VPC scope in Amazon Web Services?

I have hundreds of domains pointing to particular EIP and it would be super-sweet if it was possible to attach it to the VPC and not to loose it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, now you can. Check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#migrating-eip !!